# In Python, how to find consecutive negative numbers in a row and return column header of first negative number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame`:

`first_week_of_consecutive_Negatives`: [image: df]

This example `df` I provided is a small part of the whole df, the df continues (each column is a week). I need to find the first week (column name) where we have identified a pattern of 4 consecutive negative numbers week over week (4 consecutive weeks). I then need to assign the first column `'first_week_of_consecutive_Negatives'` with the first column name in which that pattern began.

For example:

In the image I provided, rows 2 & 3 would qualify as consecutively negative for 4 or more weeks, and I would want to return the column name in which that pattern began, in this case for both rows 2 & 3 the value for column `'first_week_of_consecutive_Negatives'` will be `'2020-12-27 00:00:00'`

Comment: You need to provide some traces of your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simplified version of your `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Week':np.nan,'2020-12-27':[9,8,-5,0,1,2],'2020-01-03':[9,-2,-1,0,1,1],'2020-01-10':[9,-3,-1,0,1,1],'2020-01-17':[8,-3,-2,0,1,1],'2020-01-24':[8,-4,-3,0,1,1]})

#    First_Week  2020-12-27  2020-01-03  2020-01-10  2020-01-17  2020-01-24
# 0         NaN           9           9           9           8           8
# 1         NaN           8          -2          -3          -3          -4
# 2         NaN          -5          -1          -1          -2          -3
# 3         NaN           0           0           0           0           0
# 4         NaN           1           1           1           1           1
# 5         NaN           2           1           1           1           1
```

First build a boolean matrix of 4x consecutive negative matches using [**`shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```py
num = 4
matches = pd.DataFrame(
    np.logical_and.reduce([df.T.iloc[1:].shift(-n).lt(0) for n in range(num)]),
    index=df.columns[1:],
    columns=df.index,
)

#                 0      1      2      3      4      5
# 2020-12-27  False  False   True  False  False  False
# 2020-01-03  False   True  False  False  False  False
# 2020-01-10  False  False  False  False  False  False
# 2020-01-17  False  False  False  False  False  False
# 2020-01-24  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Then set `First_Week` as the [**`first_valid_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```py
df['First_Week'] = matches.replace(False, np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index() if x.any() else np.nan)

#    First_Week  2020-12-27  2020-01-03  2020-01-10  2020-01-17  2020-01-24
# 0         NaN           9           9           9           8           8
# 1  2020-01-03           8          -2          -3          -3          -4
# 2  2020-12-27          -5          -1          -1          -2          -3
# 3         NaN           0           0           0           0           0
# 4         NaN           1           1           1           1           1
# 5         NaN           2           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: When I applied this to my larger df, it looks like it was able to identify the rows which had 4 consecutive negatives, however, it assigned the same value (same date) for each of these rows.

Comment: @M33S33KS Good catch, this is fixed in the updated answer (and tested with the sample data by modifying the 2nd row's negative sequence to start later).